# Python3 & WSGI Module error

Tags: python-3.x, mod-wsgi

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName superhost.gr
    ServerAdmin nikos@superhost.gr

    WSGIDaemonProcess public_html user=nikos group=nikos processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nikos/public_html/webapp.py

    ProxyPass / http://superhost.gr:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://superhost:5000/

    <Directory /home/nikos/public_html>
        WSGIProcessGroup public_html
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On

       AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi .py
       Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI

       AllowOverride None
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas as to why iam getting the above error although i have python36 isntalled along with all modules? why can it find it?

Comment: Hello, iam still facing the same problem after months i have just installed python36u-mod_wsgi module because mod_wsgi coudl not be isntalled. i reinstalled anything from scratch but still my wsgi webapp.py application wont run. please help me out. here is httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Here is the output of

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because your mod_wsgi isn't compiled for Python 3.6, or you have installed modules in a virtual environment but haven't told mod_wsgi where that virtual environment is.

For the first issue do the check in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Note you can't force mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version to use another Python versions' installation or virtual environment.

For the second, see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Hello, iam still facing the same problem after months i have just installed python36u-mod_wsgi module because mod_wsgi coudl not be isntalled. i reinstalled anything from scratch but still my wsgi webapp.py application wont run. please help me out. here is httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: You don't actually show the current error you are getting. What is it and where do you see it?

Comment: I Removed both mod_wsgi and python36u-mod_wsgi as well. I installed yum install httpd-devel to get rid of the 'apsx' issue. Here is the results of the express install.
`[root@superhost public_html]# !mod
mod_wsgi-express install-module
LoadModule wsgi_module "/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/usr" ` Do you make anyhting out of it as to why still cannot load my wsgi file? I'm still getting the forbidden error.... :-(