# Pass a list of values as options to 3 dropdown menus

Tags: python, html

how can i be able to store a list of values to  drop-down menu and then grab the value that the user selects?

```
name = month = year = ''

# populate names, months, years
names.add( '====================' )
months = ( '==========', 'Ιανουάριος', 'Φεβρουάριος', 'Μάρτιος', 'Απρίλιος', 'Μάϊος', 'Ιούνιος', 'Ιούλιος', 'Αύγουστος', 'Σεπτέμβριος', 'Οκτώβριος', 'Νοέμβριος', 'Δεκέμβριος' )
years  = ( '=====', 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019 )


pdata = pdata + '''
<br><h3><br><font color=orangeredsize=6> Επιλεκτική Αναζήτηση: </font><br>
<form method="POST" action="%s">
'''

pdata = pdata + '<select name="name"><option>%s</option></select>' % '</option><option>'.join( names )

pdata = pdata + '<select name="month"><option>%s</option></select>' % '</option><option>'.join( months )

pdata = pdata + '<select name="year"><option>%s</option></select>' % '</option><option>'.join( list( map( str, years ) ) )

pdata = pdata + '''
<br><input type="image" src="/static/img/submit.gif" name="seek" value="<Αναζήτηση>">
</form> <br><br>
''' % url_for( 'seek' )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pdata = pdata + '''
<br><h3><br><font color=orangeredsize=6> Επιλεκτική Αναζήτηση: </font><br>
<form method="POST" action="%s">

  <select name="name"><option>%s</option></select>
  <select name="month">%s</select>
  <select name="year"><option>%s</option></select>

  <br>
  <input type="image" src="/static/img/submit.gif" name="seek" value="<Αναζήτηση>">
</form> <br><br>
''' % (url_for( 'seek' ), \
   '</option><option>'.join( names ), 
   ''.join( map( lambda args: '<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (args[0],  args[1]), enumerate(months) ) ), 
   '</option><option>'.join( list( map( str, years ) ) ) )

print(pdata)
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly the way i wanted it! The look & feel is very comfortable! Perhaps you could try to enumerate the months as well so we give ti indexes? Because if i pass it like it passed the name of the month while the information in database is a epresentaive number of a month i.e. 6 foe June. ` `for i, month in enumerate(months): if i != 0: print( '<option value="%s"> %s </option>' % (i, month) ) else: print( '<option value="%s"> %s </option>' % ('==========', month) )` Can you write it perhaps a bit better?

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος, I updated the code snippet with `lambda` and `enumerate` functions. Hope this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi Elena, wow thats one complex code! :-) It has a small invalid syntax and the caret is under 'lamda (index' i tried to fix it but i couldnt. Also, are '/' at the end of liens necessary?

Comment: Hi eelna, i can't seem to find from where the syntax error occur.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος, I updated the `lambda` function in the code snipped above and it should work now. You can try it at https://repl.it/repls/FabulousDevotedMineral

Comment: It works great, thank you! Could you please help in another issue i have that i cannot get Apache run my wsgi application? i keep getting a Forbidden Error. Here is the link if you want to help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588933/python3-wsgi-module-error

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος, not sure I can help you with Apache configuration, sorry about that.

Comment: Its okey Elena, you've been more than helpfull, thanks for everything, i appreciate it!

Comment: Elena could really need your help in python this time too: Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293860/sending-file-to-the-user-gives-unicodeencodeerror

Answer (score 3):

For months use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
'<select name="month"><option>%s</option></select>' % \
    '</option><option>'.join(months)
```

And for years also use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to convert numbers to strings:

```
'<select name="year"><option>%s</option></select>' % \
    '</option><option>'.join(list(map(str, years)))
```

To get user's selected values use [`cgi`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) module:

```
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
year = form.getfirst('year')
month = form.getfirst('month')
```

Comment: Hello Elena, I've edited my initial post based on your suggestion because i cant post code in comments(i cna use backyicks but dont knwo how to leave blank lines, how do you do it?). Now i get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. Also iam using flask so i get values with the request contexts. Could you please correct what uiam still doing wrong and explain a bit? Thank you.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος, You get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` because the last string lines does not contains `%s` placeholder.  Just move `% url_for('seek')` to the first lines where `action="%s"`.

Comment: You are right! Also need to ask if there is a way to write the above code as only one whole html part leaving only the last line where i make the placeholder substitutions.

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος, please see code snipped in the next answer bellow.

Comment: Also, seems you have a typo in the attributes `<font color=orangeredsize=6>` code.