# Sending file to the user gives UnicodeEncodeError in Flask framework

Tags: python, unicode

I want to send the user a file when he clicks the appropriate button and I'm suing the following.

```
# Prepare selected file for download...
send_file( '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/' + filename )
```

But no matter what file the usser selects iam always receiving this response.

```
[Wed Sep 12 14:10:48.450211 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5172] [remote 46.103.174.201:14089]   File "/home/nikos/wsgi/downloads.py", line 182, in file
[Wed Sep 12 14:10:48.450214 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5172] [remote 46.103.174.201:14089]     send_file( '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/' + filename )
[Wed Sep 12 14:10:48.450219 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5172] [remote 46.103.174.201:14089]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 592, in send_file
[Wed Sep 12 14:10:48.450221 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5172] [remote 46.103.174.201:14089]     file = open(filename, 'rb')
[Wed Sep 12 14:10:48.450237 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 5172] [remote 46.103.174.201:14089] UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 30-39: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How will I be able to send the selected file to the user?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..
Before sending the file do,

```
file_name.encode('utf-8')
```

So pass these additional parameters to send_file(), I've got these from this [thread](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1214#issuecomment-193560116)

`attachment_filename=file_name.encode('utf-8'),as_attachment=True, conditional=True`

So your send_file might look like this...

```
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/' + filename
filepath = filepath.encode('utf-8')

send_file(attachment_filename=filepath,as_attachment=True, conditional=True)
```

Let me know if it worked so I can try further.

Comment: I'am consused. Could you please show me exactly how i should reform my code?

Comment: Post the name of the file once(`filename`). I think the filename is causing the issue.

Comment: `send_file ( filepath, attachment_filename=filepath, as_attachment=True, conditional=True )` i get `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Comment: The filename after checking ti it has the correct value. `send_file ( attachment_filename=filepath, as_attachment=True, conditional=True )` outputs this error `TypeError: send_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename_or_fp`

Comment: Try this line...

`send_file(filename.decode('utf-8'), attachment_filename=filepath, as_attachment=True )` This should probably fix your TypeError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179921/discussion-between---and-vineeth-sai).

Comment: Now i receive this: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: This `send_file( filepath, attachment_filename=filename )' does NOT produce an error but also it does not download the file either.

Comment: `# Prepare selected file for download....
filepath = '/home/nikos/wsgi/static/files/'
send_from_directory( filepath, filename, as_attachment=True )` gives this message `The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

Comment: Vineeth Sai any other suggestion?!